Hide RDCMan menu bar when using full screen
When I open a remote connection in RDCMan in full screen mode, it shows the RDCMan menu bar (with options Session and View). This causes the remote taskbar to be moved down, so it's partly off-screen.
The window actually is in full screen mode, meaning there is not a Windows title bar with maximize / restore or close buttons at the top right. There are no scrollbars either. It's just that the RDCMan menubar that is in the way.
Is there a way to hide the menu bar, or at least have the taskbar fully visible?
The RDCman version is 2.93, and the host OS is Windows 11.


You can configure the clientsize window to resize upon connection. If you double-click the titlebar at the top, it should maximize the RDCman window, and by then reconnecting, it should remove any scroll bars.

@LPChip I have that already. The window actually is in full screen mode (i.e. there are no maximize/close buttons), and I don't have have scrollbars. It's just the RDCMan menubar that I want to remove

Removing that bar would just make the clientsize window larger. That's not what you're after. You need to find out how to physicall resize the window so your taskbar fits.

@LPChip No, the client window is the correct size already: full screen, there are no scrollbars
